# Don't display first frame in Pygame (sprites)

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I am making a hit animation for a game made in `pygame` using
`sprites`. I made it and it works, but my problem is, that after the animation ends, the first frame stays on the screen.
Here is my code for the animations:

```
class HitAnimation(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

        def __init__(self,pos_x,pos_y):
            super().__init__()
            self.sprites = []
            self.is_animating = False
            self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("hit0.gif").convert_alpha())
            self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("hit1.gif").convert_alpha())
            self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("hit2.gif").convert_alpha())
            self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("hit3.gif").convert_alpha())
            self.sprites.append(pygame.image.load("hit4.gif").convert_alpha())
            self.current_sprite = 0
            self.image = self.sprites[self.current_sprite]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.topleft = [pos_x,pos_y]

        def animate(self):
            self.is_animating = True
        
        def update(self):
            if self.is_animating == True:
                self.current_sprite += 0.3

                if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
                    self.current_sprite = 0
                    self.is_animating = False

                self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]

moving_hitsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Than later in the main game function:

```
while True:
   #basic stuff, the game itself
   #than here I am updating and drawing the hit animation
   moving_hitsprites.update()
   moving_hitsprites.draw(WIN)

   if event.type==PLAYER1_HIT:
       location = HitAnimation(playerrect.x-playerrect.width//2,playerrect.y-playerrect.height//2)
       moving_hitsprites.add(location)
       location.animate() # here I am starting the animation of the hit effect
```

The animation appears, but after it goes through all the frames, and after its done it will continue to display the first frame forever. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `kill` the animation sprite when the animation ends:

```py
class HitAnimation(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        if self.is_animating == True:
            self.current_sprite += 0.3

            if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
                self.current_sprite = 0
                self.is_animating = False
 
                self.kill()                           # <---

            self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]
```

---

`kill` removes the *Sprite* from all *Groups*, so the *Sprite* will be removed from `moving_hitsprites` when the animation ends.

Actually, you don't need the `is_animating` attribute at all:

```py
class HitAnimation(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.current_sprite += 0.3
        if self.current_sprite >= len(self.sprites):
            self.current_sprite = 0
            self.kill()
        self.image = self.sprites[int(self.current_sprite)]
```